# Event handling: Sending events from base classes when the receiver expects derived classes

Tags: c++

This code distills the problem to its essence:

Infrastructure classes:

```
struct EventReceiverBase {
    virtual ~EventReceiverBase() { }
};

template<typename T>
struct EventReceiver : public virtual EventReceiverBase {
    virtual void receiveEvent(T* pSender) = 0;
};

struct EventSender {
    EventReceiverBase* pReceiver;

    template<typename T>
    void sendEvent(T* pSender) {
        EventReceiver<T>* pCastedReceiver =
            dynamic_cast<EventReceiver<T>*>(pReceiver);
        // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
        // pCastedReceiver is null. T is BaseSender. The pointer
        // being casted is really of type EventReceiver<DerivedSender>*,
        // but it tries to cast to EventReceiver<BaseSender>*, and that
        // fails.
        pCastedReceiver->receiveEvent(pSender);
    }
};
```

User classes:

```
struct BaseSender : public virtual EventSender {
    void f() {
        sendEvent(this);
    }
};
struct DerivedSender : public BaseSender { };

struct MyClass : public virtual EventReceiver<DerivedSender> {
    void receiveEvent(DerivedSender* pSender) { }
};

int main() {
    MyClass my;
    DerivedSender derivedSender;
    derivedSender.pReceiver = &my;
    derivedSender.f();
}
```

Can I recast this problem (no pun intended) to avoid this issue? I want to keep the user classes as simple as possible, while exposing the event sending and receiving functionality as close to this way as possible.

For example, I can "fix" it by making MyClass derive from EventReceiver<BaseSender> as well, but I'd really like to avoid that, as it would mean extra work in every class that receives events.

Edit: Executable paste: http://liveworkspace.org/code/4bm6OU$13

Comment: Even though `BaseSender` and `DerivedSender` are related, there is no relationship between `EventReceiver<BaseSender>` and `EventReceiver<DerivedSender>`. Therefor, pointers to those types are unrelated and the `dynamic_cast` will yield NULL. (For work-arounds, see the answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you see a problem has to do with the placement of the `f` function in the `BaseSender`: in the call to `sendEvent` below, `this` represents a pointer to `BaseSender`. Essentially, the call below

```
void f() {
    sendEvent(this);
}
```

is a short way to write this:

```
void f() {
    sendEvent<BaseSender>(this);
}
```

Moving `f` to `DerivedSender` [fixes this problem](http://ideone.com/LpM1d9).

Another alternative is making `BaseSender::f` a template:

```
template <typename T>
void f() {
    sendEvent<T>((T*)this);
}
```

and calling it like this:

```
derivedSender.f<DerivedSender>();
```

This does not look particularly nice, but may be a work-around to code copy-pasting in situations when the real-world `f` is large.

Yet another solution is to make `BaseSender` a template, like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct BaseSender : public virtual EventSender {
    void f() {
        sendEvent((T*)this);
    }
};
struct DerivedSender : public BaseSender<DerivedSender> {
};
```

This also works ([link to ideone](http://ideone.com/Fc6Urh)).

Comment: These things fix the problem in the example code, but in the real code I want to keep user classes as simple as possible, and don't contaminate them (too much) with implementation details about the event system. I've made the distinction between user classes and infrastructure classes clearer. I hope that helps.

Comment: @Marvin Well, you need to communicate the type one way or the other, otherwise the compiler wouldn't know what type you need. I added a third way of addressing the issue by making `BaseSender` a template; take a look.

Comment: None of these options are very satisfying, because they all pollute the user classes. I think it can be done with function pointers, i.e., instead of storing the address of the receiving object, I store that address and a function pointer to go with it. I can probably wrap setting these two pointers into one function that takes a receiver, so that the API exposed by the infrastructure classes remains the same. I'd lose type safety though.

Comment: @Marvin I thought the third option was rather non-intrusive: all the users need to do is adding the name of their class in angular brackets - to me, that's much better than messing around with function pointers, especially with pointers to member functions.

Comment: I'm not sure I could make that work when I have a class hierarchy of senders. Also, I found that this problem also exists in reverse, where a derived class sends the event and I want to catch it as a base class. What I did instead was, well, give up. I changed the signature of receiveEvent() to this: `virtual void receiveEvent(EventSender* pSender) = 0`. There are no templates anymore, and the user classes have to deal with casting this to the appropriate type. It's not nice, but it's easy to understand, and matches the functionality of many other eventing systems.

Answer (score 0):

This shouldn'e be a problem. pSender will point to the orignal object, unless you are doing something really weird.

However, your receiveEvent in MyClass should take a `BaseSender *` object, you'll then have to cast it to DerivedSender (or better yet, only use virtual methods defined in the base - this is how you SHOULD do things in general)